# Compatibility issues between keras and tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to ask about compatibility issues between keras and tensorflow.

Specifically, how can I find the latest compatible version of keras and tensorflow? I found a lot of places including the official website of keras and did not find how to find the tensorflow version compatible with the latest keras2.24.

My current version of tensorflow+keras is 1.4.0+2.1.0, which does not support some new features.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about having the latest Keras version, you can use the `tf.Keras` module that is already available with your Tensorflow installation. Check [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras)

As per the doc:

> tf.keras can run any Keras-compatible code, but keep in mind:
>
> The tf.keras version in the latest TensorFlow release might not be the
>   same as the latest keras version from PyPI. Check tf.keras.version.
>   When saving a model's weights, tf.keras defaults to the checkpoint
>   format. Pass save_format='h5' to use HDF5.

Answer (score 0):

I have tensorflow 1.12.0 with keras 2.2.4. I got this by downloading the latest (Anaconda3-2018.12-Windows-x86_64.exe) anaconda which has conda 4.6.4 and python 3.6.8.
I believe I then did a `conda update conda` and a `conda update anaconda`.

I then did a `conda install tensorflow` and a `conda install keras`.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't seem to fit any longer. Versions: python=3.8 and tensorflow                2.1.0 . I also get the same error as the OP using both tensorflow 2.1.0 with tensorflow-gpu 2.1.0

Comment: more stuff here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62376660/installing-tensorflow-2-gets-a-dll-failed-to-load-in-pywrap-tensorflow-py got tf2 to work with py 3.8 by using virtual environments.

Answer (score 0):

Activate your environment and update your anaconda version using

```
conda update anaconda
```

Next uninstall tensorflow and keras as below

```
pip uninstall keras
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

Install Keras and tensorflow again

```
pip install tensorflow
pip install keras
```

check the version is updated.If it is not possible comment below.